# Passing a rails model attibute value to radio buttons in a JQuery modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, radio-button

Hi there StackOverflowers, I am trying to set one of a series of 6 available options in an "upgrade" modal. In this scenario, the user has already selected and option, so the radio *should* already have and assigned value (when it is opened) that comes from the rails model. Does that make sense?  Anyway, I can seem to write the jquery to set the correct radio button based on the option that has already been selected in a previous transaction. For example, I am working with turnaround times. The customer must select a turn around time in their initial transaction, but may upgrade later, using the ui that has this modal.

Here is the javascript I've got, but it's breaking the functionallity of the site. I know it must be one simple error, but I can't see it. This works without the "if" statement and I am getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the "if" statement. When I look at the button DOM element by right clicking on it in the browser, this button is receiving the correct value as *part* of its id. I am only concerned about one very specific part of the button id, so I am using (id*="3"). I know model attributes can be accessed from the modal with backbone, but we're not using it, unfortunately.

help?

```
    $(function showTargethrs() {
    if $('button[id*='_3']') {
      $('#li_3hr').addClass("active");
      $('#updateTarget_3').prop('checked', true);
      }
    });
```